# Unity navmesh bake issue on terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain, navmesh, unity3d-terrain

I'm having this issue while baking navmesh on terrain. So many gaps on the whole terrain navmesh. An
solutions???
Note: I've converted that terrain into mesh [image: navmesh bake setting]as well but same results.

Answer (score 0):

While it is very hard to make out the geometry of your terrain from the image, it looks to me like those gaps correspond to steep hills. Try relaxing your max steepness settings and bake again.

Answer (score -2):

increasing max slope did the job.

Comment: Please avoid adding duplicate answers, instead, upvote or accept the answers that are already there.